# Suppose that * is an associative operation on a set S.

Tags: contest-math

Suppose that * is an associative operation on a set S. Define $x^n$ to mean $x*x*x*...*x$, $n$ times. (so, for example, $x^3=x*x*x.$) Suppose further that an elements $a$ of S is such that all of $a,a^2,...,a^9$ are different but $a^{10}=a^3$. Then there are some elements $b$ belonging to S such that $b=b^2$. One such elements b is:

a) $a^4$ .$\qquad$   b) $a^5$ $\qquad$  c) $a^7$ $\qquad$ d)$a^9$ $\qquad$ e) $a^{13}$

Try to do this question, but still no idea, $a^{10}=a^3\Longrightarrow a=0 \, or\, a=1$ , why this question mentioned associative operation, I don't get this.

Comment: The set $S$ need not contain elements labelled as $0$ or $1$.

Answer (score 2):

By associativity:
$$a^{10}=a^3 \implies a^{14} = a^{10}*a^{4}=a^{3}*a^{4} = a^{7}$$

Comment: Thank you for answering, now I understand.

Answer (score 1):

This question is leaned towards group theory.

$a^{10}=a^3$

We can *operate* on both side with $a$. (This is not usual multiplication)

$a*a^{10}=a*a^3$

$a^{11}=a^4$

again operate both sides with $a$

$a^{12}=a^5$

$a^{13}=a^6$

$a^{14}=a^7$
which is clearly $b^2=b$

Hence your answer must be $a^7$ **option(c)**

Comment: Thank you for the answering, I get the idea.